# How to pass parameter to netlink objects

Tags: .netlink

```
NETBlock[
    InstallNET[];
    excel=GetActiveCOMObject["Excel.Application"];
    excel@ActiveWorkbook@SaveAs["blahblah.xlsb"]
];
```

How do i pass the fileformat parameter to the netlink object SaveAs as done below in the VBA command.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "blahblah.xlsb", fileformat:=50
```